# How to fix 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I've been searching for how to fix this error but I have not been able to fix it. most answers I found deal with setting up Babel right, but I believe i have set it up like it should. I'm using Webpack to use React in my project.

My webpack config file is :

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + "/app",

  entry: {
    javascript: "./js/app.js",
    html: "./index.html",
  },

  output: {
    filename: "app.js",
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    root: path.resolve(__dirname, './app/js'),
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ["react-hot", "babel-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "file?name=[name].[ext]",
      },
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" }
    ],
  },
}
```

My index.html is :

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>React</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-weight: normal;
    }

    body {
      background: #ededef;
    }

    #app,
    .Info {
      max-width: 600px;
      padding: 40px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
    }

    hr {
      border: 0;
      border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin: 20px 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error I get is raised when I load React with `import React from 'react';` in my JS file app.js. I have installed the necessary Babel packages. I have a .babelrc file in my root folder. What can be causing this error?

EDIT

My .babelrc file is :

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you show .babelrc file ?

Comment: Not sure if this is contributing to your error, but what is the "html: "./index.html" entry point for in your webpack.config file? The entry points in webpack are used to create js bundles, but here you are pointing it to your index.html file.

Comment: @MayankShukla Added the .babelrc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your babel setup works, although you have two rules that apply to `.js`, as `/\.jsx?/` also matches `.js` because `x?` means one or zero occurrences of `x`. You should just remove the other rule.

From the error it looks like you're trying to open `app/index.html` in the browser, which imports `./js/app.js`. This is not the processed file, this is your original file with the `import` statement, so it logically fails in the browser.

First of all you need to open the file generated by webpack, in your case `dist/index.html`. But it won't find the bundle because it is located at `dist/app.js`, not `dist/js/app.js`. Because the `index.html` just gets copied (with the `file-loader` you configured), you would need to change the `<src>` tag to the following, as it's in the same directory:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to make use of the include property in your webpack loader, also you don't need to define separately `babel-loader` for `js` files since `/\.jsx?$/` syntax already checks for both

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, "app")
    ],
    loaders: [ 'react-hot', 'babel-loader' ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: "file?name=[name].[ext]",
  }
],
```

Also when you include`js` in your `html` file you should be including the compiled `js` file from webpack which recides in your `dist` folder

```
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="./dist/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use stage-0 preset :

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0
```

And the sample webpack.config.js is :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
module.exports={
devtool :'inline-source-map',
entry : ['webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8000',
'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
'./src'
] ,
output :{
path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
filename: 'bundle.js',
},
resolve:{
 modulesDirectories : ['node_modules','src'],
 extensions : ['','.js']
},
module : {
loaders :[
  {
    test : /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude : /node_modules/,
    loaders :['react-hot','babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0']
  }
]
},
 plugins :[new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
 new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]

};
```